# Django DRF: How to enable activation code for reset password using djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have been successfully able to setup a Django app with Djoser token based authentication. I want to generate a activation code / url and make the user activate through that code / link for account activation or reset password.

The [Base Endpoints](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html#user-resend-activation-e-mail) explains how to enable and utilize the activation using the endpoints. But how do I get to create the db models and generate activation code for the users? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Activation code is generated by `djoser.email.ActivationEmail` view

You only concern should be to run database migrations